# How to add the slider 3d plugin to the header?

Tags: wordpress

I am creating a website using Wordpress. To add a slideshow of images I used the [slider 3d plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/slider3d-gallery/). I added the shortcode to one of my pages, but what is happening is that the slideshow appears only in a small portion of the page. I want it to appear by the header on at least half of the page. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Could you perhaps post a screenshot or a link to the site?

Answer (score 0):

Having looked at the plugin, I think you'll need to make some modifications in order to put the Flash object into a `div` which you can then position via CSS.

Modify line 146 of `slider3d_gallery.php` from

```
$output='
```

to

```
$output='<div class="slidercontainer">
```

and then modify line 172 from

```
</object>
```

to

```
</object></div>
```

Then in your CSS you can create a new rule for your `slidercontainer` `div`:

```
.slidercontainer {
    height: 200px; /* height of your Flash object */
    position: absolute; 
    width: 400px; /* width of your Flash object */
    top: 526px; /* position you want it to be from the top of your page */
}
```

Comment: @Hello - after you make changes to a plugin, you have to de-activate and re-activate it before they'll take effect. Did you do that?